# Docker image is getting bigger and bigger

Tags: docker, containers, backup

right now I'm experimenting with Docker.

I have "installed" a Docker Debian Image.
In this Debian Environment, I installed a application.

Now, I do every night this:

- docker stop (stop container)
- docker commit (make container to an
  image)
- docker save (to save the image to an file, I do this to backup
  the current work)
- docker run (to start the container)

So as you can see, I try to create a "backup-solution".

It works perfectly. But the problem is, that the backup-files are getting bigger and bigger by every day.
Even without touchting the container for multiple days.

It used to be well under 10 gigabytes, but now it's already 20.

Why is that? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker images save "diffs" every commit you make, along with all previous versions of your image. This means that your process is guaranteed to steadily increase your final image size. To avoid this, instead of using `docker save`, you should use `docker export` instead (which receives the container as an argument, instead of an image).

[Docker save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/)

[Docker export](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/)

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it that way.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem until I figured out it's because after `docker save` the image `tar` file was generated in the same folder.

Next time when it's built again, the `tar` file is included inside the next image as well.

After added `*.tar` in my `.dockerignore` now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using `docker commit` usually isn't a best practice.  The Dockerfile system described in places like Docker's [Build and run your image](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/) tutorial will let you write a file that lists out all of the commands that need to be run to build the image.  You can check that file into source control, and run `docker build` whenever you need to recreate the image.

If the `Dockerfile` is checked in alongside the source code to your application, you can check out old versions of your application source and re-`docker build` the image from there.  There's not a particular need to save binary copies of images.

At a technical level, the images `docker commit` creates always consist of the original image, plus an additional *layer* that's whatever changed in the container.  If you repeatedly `docker commit` each image will always be larger than the image before it, even if you delete or overwrite files.  (Typical Docker images are under 1 GB, and depending on the application runtime and base image, are frequently in the 100-200 MB range.)

Comment: I got docker commit on any docker base images allways got double sizes, this is really bad design even though users should not use commit, but why anybody have to write Dockerfile for everysingle project? It's just very bad design in docker.